# WordPress php return zip file header

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to achieve force download thing (Zip File) in external API endpoint in WordPress.

Here is my part of code:

```
$filename = "info.zip";
$filepath = WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/info_folder/info_sub/";
$fulla = $filepath.$filename;
if (headers_sent()) {
    echo 'HTTP header already sent';
} else {
    if (!is_file($fulla)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
        echo 'File not found';
    } else if (!is_readable($fulla)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');
        echo 'File not readable';
    } else {
        header('content-type: application/zip; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fulla));
        readfile($fulla);
        exit;
    }
}
```

PROBLEM:
In chrome it is showing *ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE*.

This is what i am getting as header output:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=info.zip
Content-Length: 286
Content-Type: application/zip; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 19:35:51 GMT
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly i am doing wrong?

Comment: Well the part of your code you have posted is working fine for me. Does it work for you if you only use that part and nothing else on that page?

Comment: I have a lot of code inside.Would that be the reason? @Chris